# Is there a function to add text to x if x not containing y | PHP

Tags: php, function, url, web-crawler

So im working on an url crawler but i get a lot of paths without the domain and http.
And i want to make a function if the path not contain the domain and http in that to add it. 
here is my code

```
<?php
$source_url = 'http://www.google.com/';
$html = file_get_contents($source_url);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');


foreach ($links as $link) {
    $input_url = $link->getAttribute('href');
    echo $input_url . "<br>";
}



?>
```

If there is not any how i can just extract the urls containing http

Comment: You can make a function that does this.

Comment: PHP has the [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function that may help.  You cannot get what you are looking for from the DOMDocument directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://www.guru99.com/php-regular-expressions.html) to check whether the link is an absolute URL or relative i.e. contains domain or not. What I have done is check the link whether it starts with `http://` or `https://`. If it isn't then the source domain is added to the beginning of the link.

```
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $input_url = $link->getAttribute('href');

    if (!preg_match('/^https?:\/\//', $input_url)) {
        $input_url = $source_url . preg_replace('/^\//', '', $input_url);
    }

    echo $input_url . "<br>";
}
```